# Is it better to divide a single data into separate tables or keep in single table for best performance

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization, schema

I have seen few questions related to this but I felt they weren't exactly the same situation. This is also not a normalization related question.

Lets assume that we have a product which has some properties such as `name,description,price,last_update_date,stock_amount`

Lets assume, there will never be 2 different prices or stocks etc. for these 'product's and we don't have to keep historic data etc.

From a performance point of view, would it be better to keep all of these data in a single table? or divide it into seperate tables? such as:

```
products -> id, name, last_update_date, stock_amount, price

product_info -> id, products_id, description
```

I know data is not divided very logically but that is besides the point right now.

I can think of 2 arguments perhaps,

1. If you separate data into 2 tables, for example to update description, one would need to find products_id then update the data, which may cost more. On the other hand the products table's storage footprint would be so much smaller. Does this help in efficiency when finding the product, for example by name? or since we would have an index for 'name' it wouldn't matter how big the table is on disk?
2. Well, if everything was in one table, we wouldn't need to work on separate tables and this may increase efficiency?

What do you think? and what do you base your opinion on? Links and benchmark results are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Well... depends. Keeping everything in one table might speed up things because it removes the need for joins. But keeping only the "core" product data in one table might speed up things because you only have to load the description if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is a 1-to-1 mapping, there's no strong reason not to keep it all in one table. You should still have an ID column, so that if you have other data that's 1-to-many or many-to-many, you can refer to the products by ID in those tables.

However, one benefit of splitting it up into different tables can be improved concurrency. If everything is in one table, then an update to that table will lock the entire row (or the entire table if you use MyISAM). If you split it into multiple tables, then an update to one of the those tables won't interfere with queries that use the other tables.

Comment: This sounds reasonable and concurrency is not a problem for this example. I was just wondering if database uses indexes to close in to a record, then have to scan X records to find the correct one, for example using the 'name', does this cause jumps in disk because it has to skip 'descrption' for each record? or records are arranged in disk such as it can read 'name' fields consequtively?

Comment: The specific layout depends on the database engine, e.g. MyISAM versus InnoDB.

Comment: Assuming we are using InnoDB, then what?

Comment: http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/03/the-basics-of-innodb-space-file-layout/ explains how InnoDB stores its tables.

Comment: Talk about `INDEXes`, not about "closing in on a record".  What indexes does the table have?  What are your `WHERE` clauses like?

Comment: @RickJames It is a hyphothetical table. Therefore we assume the indexes are created properly in both cases. I would imagine an example query would be finding a product which is in stock and has a word in description, lets say 'spray'.

Comment: @Barmar so what if the query I need to form requires finding a value in description and also checking the stock value is positive? Would it then be better to have a single table instead of trying to join the results?

Comment: It's hard to give a general answer to these hypothetical questions, but it probably doesn't make a huge difference. If you have two tables, it will pick one of them to do the search in, then find the corresponding record in the other table using the index and check for the second table's criteria.

Comment: Today I found an interesting documentation page on MySQL site. Actually the documentation has some hints about when it may be useful to divide the data into multiple tables. But then the results still depend on how the queries are formed. So I gather it is best to start with a single table, then divide if performance becomes an issue because of using a single table. Otherwise making unnecessary optimizations just make the code more complicated.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score -1):

I think efficiency is better with a single table. Two tables may be useful for further scalability.

Comment: I am looking for an explanation of why you are thinking that?

Comment: I thoutht it was common sense: if you have one single table, MySQL just have to reand and update one single table, so efficiency should be better. In other hand, if you have two tables and the system scales to many users, concurrency should be better. And if you scale to more items and more descriptions, multiple tables should make it easier to manage.

Comment: I realized common sense fails for technology quite often. Because once it is true, does not mean it is true forever.

Can you tell why having two tables would scale better? Because lets say you have 50 mysql threads looking for data. It should be even more efficient to have all the data in the same table compared to 50 tables (due to table and system caches etc.). You are right, only if the table was locked, but in innodb it is row level so this is a problem for very specific situations I think.

Comment: I didn't mean to have a table for each thread, but a table for each group of data. So, if you separate products from their info, each separate access would requiere less info to be read or written into cache. That's why performance would be better.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by 'group of data'. In either case, I think this idea requires some benchmarking. I found many threads asking for single/multiple table performance question but no answer has some links to benchmark results. The recommended and official way of dividing the data is to partition the table, not try to make many small tables. I couldn't find MySQL pages saying anything also, sounds like word of mouth and "common sense" again. Should I call mythbusters? :) (too bad they don't make new episodes anymore)

Comment: Less info to be read in each access means better performance. There is no much hidden tricks there, so in this case, at least, common sense may be right. You can benchmark the two options yourself to confirm it.

Comment: But how can you know that less info is read. Because MySQL will jump to result rows using the index. It doesn't really matter how big each row is in that case.
Today I found a good documentation page when I was reading about MySQL indexes. It says dividing the data into several tables "may" provide less disk operations. It also says it may help to have more primary keys when there are multiple tables.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-foreign-keys.html
So if I test this now, results will be inconsistent based on how I access the data.

Comment: It all depens on how you will access data and how you index tables. If you will have to access to the whole data, so having it in multiple tables will requiere multiple access. If you will have to acces only some portion of data each time, having that portion of data in a single table will be more efficient. Another issue is scalability: if you plan to scale data and kind of accesses, it will be more efficient to have different tables so you will be able to structure more complex data and access each portion separately.